# Change xmlns too when changing charset?

Tags: declaration, xml-namespaces

Should I alter the xmlns into 'el' from 'en' when setting up a webpage in ISO-8859-7 (Greek)? So it would be:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="el" lang="el">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing character encoding and language.

If you want to display a webpage in Greek, then use "el". It doesn't matter (much) what encoding you use, but I would use UTF-8 or plain ASCII (gotta love XML entity references!).

If you see "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-7" and are using it to determine what language to display in... how old is the browser you're targeting? Does it offer no better way to set a language?

(Admittedly Windows didn't do i18n sensibly for ages — you had to download updates/patches for your language or they would refuse to install, making "ENU" the most practical choice for many people. ISTR that they fixed this in Vista or 7.)

Comment: Thanks, very informative. I did not confused the namespace attribute of html tag with charset. I know my charset is in Greek (ISO-8859-7) but the namespace attribute in html opening tag is something belonging to XML and I don't know XML that well. From a web search I've clarified that it propably (not sure yet) need a change to 'el': http://www.bentoweb.org/ts/XHTML1_TestSuite3/metadata/sc3.1.1_l1_017